# Split set of intervals into minimal set of disjoint intervals

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, intervals

How can I efficiently split a set of intervals (the *input* set) into a minimal set of disjoint intervals (the *output* set), in such a way that all intervals from the input set can be expressed as unions of intervals from the output set ?

Examples :

```
Input: [0,9] [2,12]
Output: [0,1] [2,9] [10,12]

Test :
[0,9] = [0,1] ∪ [2,9]
[2,12] = [2,9] ∪ [10,12]

Input: [0,Infinity] [1,5] [4,6]
Output: [0,0] [1,3] [4,5] [6,6] [7,Infinity]

Test :
[0,Infinity] = [0,0] ∪ [1,3] ∪ [4,5] ∪ [6,6] ∪ [7,Infinity]
[1,5] = [1,3] ∪ [4,5]
[4,6] = [4,5] ∪ [6,6]
```

I need to do this in Javascript. Here is the idea I tried :

```
// The input is an array of intervals, like [[0,9], [2,12]], same for the output

// This function converts a set of overlapping
// intervals into a set of disjoint intervals...
const disjoin = intervals => {
  if(intervals.length < 2)
    return intervals
  const [first, ...rest] = intervals
  // ...by recursively injecting each interval into
  // an ordered set of disjoint intervals
  return insert(first, disjoin(rest))
}

// This function inserts an interval [a,b] into
// an ordered set of disjoint intervals
const insert = ([a, b], intervals) => {
  // First we "locate" a and b relative to the interval
  // set (before, after, or index of the interval within the set
  const pa = pos(a, intervals)
  const pb = pos(b, intervals)

  // Then we bruteforce all possibilities
  if(pa === 'before' && pb === 'before') 
    return [[a, b], ...intervals]
  if(pa === 'before' && pb === 'after')
    // ...
  if(pa === 'before' && typeof pb === 'number')
    // ...
  // ... all 6 possibilities
}

const first = intervals => intervals[0][0]
const last = intervals => intervals[intervals.length-1][1]

const pos = (n, intervals) => {
  if(n < first(intervals))
    return 'before'
  if(n > last(intervals))
    return 'after'
  return intervals.findIndex(([a, b]) => a <= n && n <= b)
}
```

But it is very inefficient. In the `pos` function, I could do a binary search to speed things up, but I mainly wonder if :

- This is a known problem and has a name in the algorithmic world
- There is an optimal solution which has nothing to do with what I tried

Comment: What have you tried and what problem are you having?

Comment: I updated my question with more details.

Comment: This is a very nice question. I will answer once i have time. As a hint we need to use  the non-existent [`Array.unfold()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50114262/4543207) though. But no worries. It's just a way of creating an array from a seed value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every boundary point in the input set also needs to be in the output set.  The interval between each adjacent pair of boundary points is in the output if it's inside at least one input.

```
splitIntervals = (input) => {
    const starts = input.map(x => [x[0],1]);
    const ends = input.map(x => [x[1]+1, -1]);   
    let count=0;
    let prev=null;
    return [...starts, ...ends]
        .sort((a,b) => (a[0] - b[0])) //sort boundary points
        .map(x => {
            //make an interval for every section that is inside any input interval
            const ret= (x[0] > prev && count !== 0 ? [prev, x[0]-1] : null);
            prev=x[0];
            count+=x[1];
            return ret;
        })
        .filter(x => !!x);
}
```

Test:

```
> splitIntervals([ [0,9], [2,12] ])
[ [ 0, 1 ], [ 2, 9 ], [ 10, 12 ] ]
> splitIntervals([[0,9], [3,9], [4,13]])
[ [ 0, 2 ], [ 3, 3 ], [ 4, 9 ], [ 10, 13 ] ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Matt's answer, this collects all points, and builds the output from that, keeping count so to detect gaps between intervals.

Difference is that here the first phase excludes duplicates (based on a `Map`) instead of filtering them out later, and the last phase is written in a slightly more *functional programming* style:

```js
const disjoint = intervals =>
    [...intervals.reduce((acc, [first, last]) =>
        acc.set(first, (acc.get(first )||0) + 1).set(last+1,(acc.get(last+1)||0) - 1)
    , new Map)]
    .sort((a,b) => a[0]-b[0])
    .reduce(([prev, inside, res], [curr, change]) =>
        [curr, inside+change, (!inside || res.push([prev, curr-1]), res)]
    , [0, 0, []] )
    .pop();

console.log(disjoint([[0,9], [2,12]]));
console.log(disjoint([[0,Infinity],[1,5],[4,6]]));
console.log(disjoint([[0,6],[1,2],[3,6],[6,6],[7,9],[7,8]]));
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be mapped to the graph coloring problem where each interval is a vertex, edges connect vertices (intervals) that have an overlap, colors represent sets to which intervals belong to. As per definition of the graph coloring problem, two connected vertices (two overlapping intervals) should not have the same color (should belong to different sets)

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring

The Welsh Powell algorithm can be used to get good solutions (not guaranteed to be optimal).

See https://gist.github.com/printminion/a337eeb63ba232084dfc